# What are the the actual similarities between Electric Circuits and magnetic circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, vectors, short-circuits

I have surfed google to find an answer to that but all I keep seeing is "differences" and not actual similarities.
So what exactly do electric circuits and magnetic circuits have in common.I wanna know as many as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of a "magnetic circuit" exploits a one-to-one correspondence between the equations of the magnetic field in an unsaturated ferromagnetic material to that of an electrical circuit. Using this concept the magnetic fields of complex devices such as transformers can be quickly solved using the methods and techniques developed for electrical circuits.

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit